# How to remove some pairs from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like [[2,3], [7,6], [12,567],[18,4]]. I need to remove a pair, when second element of pair is bigger than 5.

```
for x in table:
    if x[1] > 5:
        del x
```

I tried this way, but *list index out of range*. How to do it correctly?

Comment: You have a list of lists, so you need `x[0][1]`

Comment: Never delete from the list/dict you are iterating through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
table = [[2,3], [7,6], [12,567],[18,4]]
table = [x for x in table if not x[1] > 5]
```

You may want to learn more about the concept of list comprehensions. I find this article gives a good introduction:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

There is a `filter` function in Python:

```py
new_table = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] <= 5, table))
```